# D3 zoom behavior change in v3 breaking map tile example

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am building a tiled map based on d3. So I found [the corresponding d3 example](http://bl.ocks.org/tmcw/3943330) and copy pasted its code to start my implementation. I need to add overlays to the map so went on and discovered they were misplaced and did not follow the map tiles when zooming. I spent a lot of time bisecting the difference between my adapted copy-paste and the original example and found out this was due to the fact that the example uses v2 of d3 and I am using v3.

My findings is that the main change between v2 and v3 is the behavior of the zoom and translation together. So I tested by zooming and printing the translation vector, and my findings are:
In v2, the `projection.translate` vector is kept unchanged if the mouse cursor is **on the (lat,long) = 0,0)** on the initial tile.
In v3, the `projection.translate` vector is kept unchanged if the mouse cursor is **on the top left (most NW point)** of the initial tile.

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmwq13r4/) in which I copy-pasted the example code, added my debug dots that should cover the earth plus a dot on Paris to see if alignment with the tiles is correct.
You will note that Paris is not correctly placed, (but would be if you run this on d3 v2).

So I guess now there is just some Math to do on my side to update the initial example logic, probably where the `tile_origin` or tile translation computation.is made. I just started to try to fix them but this seem not trivial. So I am asking here if anybody has an idea of what to change in the example to have it working in v3 (i.e. having a red dot following Paris whatever the zoom level is).
I also could not find any related change in the v3 changelog, if any knows what exactly changed this could help me.

Comment: I would recommend either sticking to v2 or starting from an example that uses v3, like [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4150951).

Comment: indeed I decided to do that, I started from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797 and had it working just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the best solution is to start from scratch from a v3 example, like http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4132797 (which I tried and succeeded with) or http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4150951 as Lars Kotthoff commented.